# Codeigniter form submit but no Db Query using my model

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

Learning CodeIgniter 3 and trying to do a simple search to query the Db... :-)

I built my Controller, The model that must query the Db, and the view that contains both the results and the search field...

My form actually submit and I get the $_POST array after submit on the form... But it seems the model, even being called (or not correctly!?!?!) is not querying the Db... Why not?

Search.php controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
          public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->database();
                $this->load->helper('text');
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $this->load->helper('form') ;
                //$this->load->library('MY_sphinxclient');

                $this->load->model('Search_model');
        }
    public function index()
    {

      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
      {
        $this->load->view('search');
      }
      else
      {
      $data['search']=$this->input->get_post('search');
      $this->Search_model->get_search($data);
      $this->load->view('search');
      }
    }
      }
```

Search_model.php

```
<?php
        class Search_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        }
        public function get_search($search_submit)
        {         
          $sql = "SELECT  ads.id AS id, 1 AS table_id, location, provLabel, text,
          R_rand, addate, adcat.name AS catname, adsubcat.name AS subname, f_value 
          FROM ads 
          JOIN search_town ON search_town.townId=ads.townId 
          JOIN search_region ON search_region.regionId=search_town.relRegionId 
          JOIN search_prov ON search_prov.provId=search_region.relProvId 
          JOIN adcat ON adcat.id=ads.catid 
          JOIN adsubcat ON adsubcat.id=ads.subcatid 
          LEFT JOIN adfields ON adfields.ad_id=ads.id 
          WHERE ads.adactive=1 AND ads.subcatid!=841 AND scam=0 AND ads.catid!=8
          AND (text LIKE '%$search_submit%' OR f_value LIKE '%$search_submit%')";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query->result();
          $result= $query->result();
          echo count($result);

        }

        }
```

My simple view search.php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World!!!';
if(isset($_POST)){
var_dump($_POST);
}

echo form_open('search');
echo form_label('Search: ');
$data_name = array(
'name' => 'search',
'id' => 'search',
'placeholder' => 'Search'
);
echo form_input($data_name);
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close( );

if(isset($search)){
echo '<table>';
foreach($search as $rows) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$rows->id.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->text.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

search_submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is named `Search_model` but you are using `$this->search_model`.

Shouldn't this:

```
$this->search_model
```

Be:

```
$this->Search_model
```

Or maybe you should specify a name when performing the load:

```
$this->load->model('Search_model', 'search');
$this->search->get_search();
```

Checking your latest edit:

```
$this->load->model('Search_model', 'search');
$this->search->get_search($seach); //Shouldn't $search be $this->input->get_post('search')
```

Comment: I changed my model as follow... And now get errors.
       public function index()
       {
          $this->load->model('Search_model', 'search');
          $this->search->get_search($search);
        }

Comment: My apologies... I made changes to my controller and get the following error

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: search
Filename: controllers/Search.php
Line Number: 21
Will update controller above

Comment: Shouldn't $search be $this->input->get_post('search')?x

Comment: You are not declaring $search variable anywhere in your changes.

Comment: My apologies... But I am truly lost here ;-)
Can you give me an example on to how to declare $search correctly then?

Comment: Ok, I think I did declare it now and edited my controller above. But still no results ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Make your equals on form_validation instead of === use ==

Make sure you load form_validation library

Your missing form_validation->set_rules()

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        // I would autoload Database
        $this->load->database(); 

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('search_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('search', 'Search');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('search');

        } else {

            $data['search'] = $this->input->post_get('search');

            $this->search_model->get_search($data);

            $this->load->view('search');

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this sorted.
To do a simple query of the Db, for example, to create a search form inside Codeigniter 3

Thanks for everybody's help!

The controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
          public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->database();
                $this->load->helper('text');
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $this->load->helper('form') ;
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('fsearch', 'Search', 'required');
                //$this->load->library('MY_sphinxclient');

                $this->load->model('Search_model');

        }
        public function index()
        {

          if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
          {
            $this->load->view('search');
          }
          else
          {
          $fsearch=$this->input->get_post('fsearch');
          $data['results']=$this->Search_model->get_search($fsearch);
          $this->load->view('search', $data);
          }
        }

      }
```

The Model:

```
<?php
        class Search_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        }
        public function get_search($search)
        {         
          $sql = "SELECT  ads.id AS id, 1 AS table_id, location, provLabel, text,
          R_rand, addate, adcat.name AS catname, adsubcat.name AS subname, f_value 
          FROM ads 
          JOIN search_town ON search_town.townId=ads.townId 
          JOIN search_region ON search_region.regionId=search_town.relRegionId 
          JOIN search_prov ON search_prov.provId=search_region.relProvId 
          JOIN adcat ON adcat.id=ads.catid 
          JOIN adsubcat ON adsubcat.id=ads.subcatid 
          LEFT JOIN adfields ON adfields.ad_id=ads.id 
          WHERE ads.adactive=1 AND ads.subcatid!=841 AND scam=0 AND ads.catid!=8
          AND (text LIKE '%$search%' OR f_value LIKE '%$search%') GROUP BY ads.id ORDER BY ads.id DESC LIMIT 20";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query->result();
           echo 'Search Done';
        }

        }

?>
```

The View:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World!!!';
if(isset($_POST)){
var_dump($_POST);
}

echo form_open('search');
echo form_label('Search: ');
$data_name = array(
'name' => 'fsearch',
'id' => 'search',
'placeholder' => 'Search'
);
echo form_input($data_name);
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close( );

if(isset($results)){
echo '<table>';
foreach($results as $rows) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$rows->id.'</td>
            <td>'.$rows->text.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```